# Path of deployment yaml in kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, etcd, kubernetes-apiserver, kubernetes-cluster

When we run the below command from root user in kubernetes master node:

- kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginxD

on which path the yaml file gets stored ?

- kubectl get deployment nginx  -o yaml

from which path it provides us the yaml body ?

Answer (score 1):

Raw k8s stores everything within etcd.  When running commands like `kubectl get deployment nginx -o yaml` kubectl talks to the kubeapi which talks to etcd to get the yaml for you.

etcd is a key-value store so any `kubectl get XYZ` is reading a specific key.  Any `kubectl create XYZ` is creating a new key/value within etcd.

Because of the importance of etcd within k8s, it is heavily recommended you back it up in production environments.

The components and how they talk to everything can be found here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/

Comment: Appreciate you response ! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's never going to create any yaml. It's create a deployment. when  you run this `kubectl get deployment nginx -o yaml`. The deployment just showed in yaml format.

Comment: appreciate you answer.
So what is the best practice, creating a yaml files for everything and storing them in any directory OR directly using a command to create any deployment ?

Comment: @user3839347 it's always better if you create any kind of kubernetes object with yaml. because you can add all kind of spec when you are using yaml to create any k8s instance. but there are limitation when you use command.